# Running 2 instances of JBoss on 1 machine. Getting "not enough space" error running native command

Tags: java, unix, memory, jboss, java-native-interface

We have a 64 bit JBoss instance that deploys an axis web service, which is just the front end face to run a native executable command. When the web service is called, it executes this native executable command. The 64 bit instance runs with 3gb of memory.

We recently introduced a 2nd instance of JBoss running on the same physical machine. It runs in 32 bit mode, because it has to run some JNI 32 bit code. This second instance of JBoss is bound to ports-01 so that it runs on 8180 (basically +100 of the default JBoss ports). This instance runs with 512MB of memory.

Since introducing this second instance of JBoss, we are receiving "not enough space" error messages when the 64 bit instance tries to execute the native executable command when it is called. It's an IOException from java, from the unix forkAndExec command. Everything I read, says this has something to do with swap file size. Using the unix, top command, it looks like the swap file size never changes, and it is 3gb. When we run the 64 bit instance first, there seem to be no issues with this, but if the 32 bit instance starts first, we get this error. I'm wondering if the two instances are competing for resources, or if we really are running out of swap space from unix. I'm not sure if JBoss uses swap space and how much it uses, or does Java handle that?

I guess I'm looking for any ideas or suggestions for a solution about this problem. The main pattern I seem to see is that if the 64 bit instance starts first, the native executable works fine, but if the 32 bit instance starts first, it has issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a swap space issue after all. We had 8GB of memory and 4GB of swap. One server was using 800MB of swap and the other 3.8GB of SWAP, which barely put us over our limit.

Instead of using the "top" command in unix, we had to use swap -s to view the available size of swap space, and that was more accurate.

We created a temporary swap file with a command like mkfile 10240M /opt/myswapfile. Then we added it to the swap area on the server with a command swap -a /opt/myswapfile.

Now they seem to be working fine together.

Answer (score 0):

The OS handles swap space, Java has no idea about these things. Running any part of Java in the swap space is a very bad idea in any case.

I would make sure there is plenty of main memory after these two programs are running (not just the heaps but the total memory used by these processes)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about what Java is doing running in swap space. From what I read, the forAndExec command uses swap space to create a new process instance or something if enough memory isn't available. There are 8gb on the server itself, but the 64 bit instance uses 3 of them. I would think it could split 1 more time and use 6, then if it splits again, 9 that would then need swap space. We have 4 of these processes kicking off and normally 1 of the 4 will fail. If each 1 uses 3, that would be 12 gb total just for those 4 processes. Maybe swap is the problem, when I put it that way.